# numpy, understanding of ndarray.base

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have tried the following experiment to understand views and copies in numpy using two dimensional arrays.

As we can see below, the slicing creates a view (a) and the indexing with a list of integers creates a copy (c.base is not the same as arr and d.base is None). This is the expected behaviour according to my understanding.

What I do not understand is why c.base is not None and why c.flags.owndata is False. If this is a fresh copy why is this happening?

I note that this is not the case with d view.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2,4,8],
                [16, 32, 64, 128],
                [256, 512, 1024, 2048]])
print(arr)
print(arr.base)
print(arr.flags.owndata)
# [[   1    2    4    8]
#  [  16   32   64  128]
#  [ 256  512 1024 2048]]
# None
# True

# this is a view, identical base to arr.base
a = arr[:,1:3]
print(a)
print(a.base)
print(np.shares_memory(a, arr))
print(a.flags.owndata)
# [[   2    4]
#  [  32   64]
#  [ 512 1024]]
# [[   1    2    4    8]
#  [  16   32   64  128]
#  [ 256  512 1024 2048]]
# True
# False

# this is a copy, its own base, does not share memory with arr
c = arr[:,[1,3]]
print(c)
print(c.base)
print(np.shares_memory(c, arr))
print(c.flags.owndata)
# [[   2    8]
#  [  32  128]
#  [ 512 2048]]
# [[   2   32  512]
#  [   8  128 2048]]
# False
# False

# this is a copy, no base, does not share memory with arr
d = arr[[1,2], :]
print(d)
print(d.base)
print(np.shares_memory(d, arr))
print(d.flags.owndata)
# [[  16   32   64  128]
#  [ 256  512 1024 2048]]
# None
# False
# True
```

Comment: `b` can use the `a` databuffer by just using its own offset, shape and strides.  With `c` and `d` it can't do that - columns or rows have been selected individually (via the list), so they have to have their own databuffer.  If you can't accept our word for it (or the numpy indexing documentation), you may need to read some numpy basics that describe how arrays are stored.

Comment: I replied to a number of recent questions by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4281353/mon, who was also trying to understand indexing.  I used the `__array_interface__` to identify `view` vs `copy` (I think that's more informative than `base`.

Answer (score 0):

The case for `a` is of **slicing**, where always a reference is returned. Cases `c` and `d` comprise **indexing** which always returns a copy. Read more about it [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

The difference between `c` and `d` is thus:

For `c`, since all rows are to be copied, but only select columns,
<s>what internally happens is, the original array is transposed and stored in the new ndarray; then unselected columns (rows in the new nd-array) are dropped. Then a transpose is returned (this is evident from the results of printing `c` and `c.base`).</s>

For `d`, since rows are selected in dis-continuous fashion (with all columns for that row) and [since C style row-major order is used internally](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/source/reference/arrays.ndarray.rst#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray)(*well, depends*), the new ndarray is populated (copied, thus no base) directly from the original array.

**EDIT**:

As per the information [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/internals.code-explanations.html#advanced-indexing), when discontinuous rows are indexed (as in `d`), individual rows are copied and stacked.
Extending this idea, I **presumed** that for discontinuous columns (as in `c`), performing a 3 step operation would be more meaningful:

1. Transpose the original array
2. Copy the selected columns (now rows) into new nd-array (this has to be stored as a *base*)
3. Transpose the base, and return

I have to admit I did not find official documentation for this.

Comment: Where do you get the informaiton about transposing and dropping in the `c` case?  I think instead it is creating a (3,2) array, and copying the selected columns over.  With `strides` numpy can index columns just as easily as rows.

Comment: @hpaulj I think `strides` simply helps numpy figure out the bounds for a row end. This is my understanding as per [this link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html).

Comment: [This link](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/numpy/reference/internals.code-explanations.html) makes me feel, `fancy-indexing` as implemented in current stable releases of numpy is far more involved. Although they have a **3-step** process, it is _way_ different than what I have mentioned!

Comment: The details of how the `c` code makes the copy aren't important to most users.  This page, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing, plus familiarity with the rules of broadcasting, should be enough.